# Maximum number of objects in an array for a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have this class:

```
class tree
{
public: 
    int row;
    int column;
};
```

I want to create a total of around 1024 objects for the class `tree` but if I increase the value to above 90 in `tree a[90]` it gives a `segmentation fault`:

```
tree a[90]; //Ok
tree a[1024]; //Segmentation fault
```

Is there a max limit on the number of objects we can create or is there any other work around to create 1024 objects in the form of an array?

Comment: A 1440-720 byte stack seems small.  What system are you on?  What compiler?  Is that actually what `tree` contains, or did you simplify it to the point of not actually generating the same bug?  I really, really doubt the above program is causing the problem described, and if so your problem won't be fixed by avoiding stack allocation probably.

Comment: You are probably hitting the memory capacity limit rather than the object count limit.  Try using dynamic memory.

Comment: Also, try using `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: is that **whole** code? have you removed anything from `class tree` like (i.e. array of items in the tree) before you pasted it here?

Comment: deleted my bad comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a max limit on the no. of objects we can create?

Well, yes. It's called the stack limit. It depends on how big your stack is. Your stack size here is:

```
stack_size = sizeof(int) * 2 * 90
```

If on your platform `sizeof(int)` is 4 (which it typically is), you have `4 * 2 * 90 = 720 bytes` of stack, which seems *very* small.

Either way, the correct way of allocating large amounts of objects is on the *heap*, which typically has more space then the stack:

```
//std::vector allocates its elements on the heap
std::vector<tree> a(1024);
```

If you can't use `std::vector` for some reason, you can still use the old school style dynamic array (*not recommended* though):

```
tree* a = new tree[1024];
```

Comment: Why do you say arrays are not recommended? Which language authority is saying that?

Comment: @Dai I'm not saying that. I'm just saying that dynamic memory management using pointers and manual heap allocation is bad practice, as if 1) you forget to delete `a` or 2) somewhere between `new` and `delete` an exception is thrown, you'll get a memory leak. This wouldn't happen if you used RAII to manage the memory, like `std::vector` does.